# How to design content type for students results

Tags: views

I have a content type for "Students Grades" which has fields to hold the students exam results for every student and every subject as following:

```
==========================
| field           | type |
==========================
| student_name    | text |
| class           | text |
| math_points     | text |
| sport_points    | text |
| activity_points | text |
==========================
```

And, I would like to present students grades as below:

```
Student Name: John Smith
Class: Primary 1st
================================
| Subject  | Max | Min | Result |
=================================
| Math     | 30  | 15  | 28     |
| Sport    | 10  | 5   | 8.5    |
| Activity | 20  | 10  | 17     |
=================================
```

The problem for me how to include the values of columns "Max" and "Min", which hold unique values on level of the "Subject" and "Class".

For example, the Max for Math is always 30 points for all students in Primary 1st class, but it could be 40 points in Primary 2nd class. Same applies into "Min" column.

So the question is, what's the simplest design strategy of the content type/views to include every subject result, max and min points without creating too much fields?

Comment: You need to include info about how its all linked together

Comment: @NiallMurphy I tried to clarify it more. Let me know if any point is not clear enough.

Comment: I can't really answer properly. I'm used to this sort of system using multiple content types with thinks linked together.. I'd recommend looking at https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pivot and letting each subject be its own column with Max/Min at the top.